# Adding Duplicate Content Placeholders for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, duplicates, placeholder

I am working on our intranet that utilizes a custom .master page. One content placeholder that refers to the search functionality of SharePoint is being utilized in the footer ().

In our site mockup, we envisioned two search boxes, one in the top of the site, above the nav and one in the footer. I thought, easy, I just duplicate that content placeholder which brought up a duplication error from Sharepoint.

My question is this: Is there a way to duplicate content placeholders without needing to create a custom placeholder? And if not, is creating a custom placeholder the best way to go about this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to customize this.

- Direct master page change
- Add (custom) place holder to master page
- Use delegate controls (no master page change required)

Delegate controls allow you to create a regular user control (.ascx) and assign it a sequence number so that it becomes attached to an existing master page control. Using delegates could potentially allow you to attach the same user control to two different controls (delegates).

With all the recent "don't change the master page" buzz, it is becoming ever more relevant, although for on-premise scenarios, you can be a bit more eccentric.

Not only you can't duplicate place holders, but you should also be very careful while removing or even adding existing place holders, no matter how irrelevant they may appear to be. Even their original order matters (e.g. PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea, PlaceHolderLeftNavBar).

refs,

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/08/missing-apps-you-can-add-with-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.eliostruyf.com/missing-apps-can-add-zone-adding-new-app/

http://www.eliostruyf.com/document-set-view-not-visible-in-sharepoint-2013/

examples,

https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages/

http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-delegate-control/

Comment: Hello, sir! Thank you for your succinct response! I'll dive into these articles you've posted and come up with a solution that best handles the scenario!